# Diagonalizable operator implies every generalized eigenvector is an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, generalized-eigenvector

I don't understand the proof below from Artin's *Algebra*. Can someone please explain? My specific questions are below.

[image]

Suppose $T$ is diagonalizable, so the matrix $\Lambda = [T]_\mathbf{B}$ with respect to $\mathbf{B}$ is diagonal with each $v_i \in \mathbf{B}$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Now let $v$ be a generalized eigenvector, so $(T - \lambda I_n) \circ (T - \lambda I_n) \circ \dots \circ (T - \lambda I_n) (T(v) - \lambda v)=0$, i.e. $(T - \lambda I_n)^k(v) = 0$ for some $k > 0$. Then Artin write "we replace $T$ by $T - \lambda$ to reduce to the case that $T^k v = 0$." I do not understand this step at all.

The coordinates of $T^kv$ are $[T^kv]_\mathbf{B} = [T^k]_\mathbf{B} [v]_\mathbf{B} = \Lambda^k (x_1, \dots, x_n)^t$, so I agree that if $T^k v = 0$, then the coordinates of $T^kv$ are $\lambda_i^kx_i = 0$ with scalars $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$, so $\lambda_i = 0$ or $x_i = 0$ for each $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. How do we then conclude that $Tv = 0$? I think it relates to the "we replace $T$ by $T - \lambda$" step...

Comment: for the second part, is there any way for you to have $\lambda_i^k = 0$ without $\lambda_i = 0$? And for the first half, I'm not _sure_ but I think he's just saying that $T - \lambda$ is just another diagonal matrix, so we can just ignore the lambda and treat the case $T$.

Comment: Replace T by T_$lambda$ means that it is assumed without loss of generality that the Eigen value $lambda=0$

Comment: $\lambda_i^k = 0 \implies \lambda_i = 0$ because of the zero-product property.
@LawrenceMano how can we assume that the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Answered by @Berci very clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simply name $T-\lambda I_n$ to something, say, $S$. (They kept calling it $T$, and it seems it might cause confusions.)
   $S$ is still diagonalizable in basis $B$, with same generalized eigenvectors but with $0$ as the corresponding eigenvalue.
   (Simply $(T-\lambda I_n)^kv=0$ becomes $S^kv=0$.)
2. Assuming $S={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and $v=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$, we have
   $$S^r(v)=(\dots,\, {\lambda_i}^rx_i,\dots)^T$$
   for any $r\in\Bbb N$, in particular for $r=k$ and for $r=1$ as well.
   So, if $S^kv=0$, then for each index $i$, either $x_i=0$ or $\lambda_i=0$, but in this case $S(v)$ is also $0$ by the above.

Comment: Aha! So "we replace $T$ by $T - \lambda$" should read "we relabel $T - \lambda$ as $T$." Then $S = T$ is also diagonalizable, and $v$ is a generalized eigenvector for $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ and exponent $k$. So $S^k v = 0$, so either the $i$th diagonal entry of $S$ is $0$ or the $i$th coordinate of $v$ is $0$. In either case, the coordinates of $Sv$ are all zero, so $Sv = 0$, i.e. $Tv = \lambda v$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If not the Jordan normal form won't be diagonal.

Comment: So (c) implies (a).

Comment: Actually $(a)\implies (c)$.  Or, as I stated it, $\lnot(c)\implies\lnot(a)$.

Comment: I'm confused. I think $(c) \implies (a)$ because if all the blocks are $1 \times 1$, then the Jordan form is diagonal, so $T$ is diagonalizable. How does diagonalizable imply that the Jordan form is diagonal? Or for $\neg (c) \implies \neg (a)$, how does "Jordan form is not diagonal" imply "not diagonalizable"?

Comment: Well, they are all equivalent.  So each implies the other.  As far as I know, the Jordan form will be diagonal if it's diagonalizable.